# Use CSS to break up a long string in two equal-length lines

Tags: css, word-wrap, word-break

I have a long URL that doesn't fit in the container width in mobile view, so I added `word-wrap:break-word;` to the container.  The result is a very long string on one line and a very short remainder of the string on the second line.

How do you make both lines have the same number of characters (so they can have the same width?)

Comment: CSS can't do this predictably alone unless your font-size, font-spacing, font-weight, etc are all fixed static values across all devices you could do something like @obsidianage suggests, but again it works because char length is 85 which is evenly divisible so 42 chars per line and strictly relies on static values for any sizing considerations. You could however use javascript and get it pretty accurate between any sizing so long as the character length is evenly divisible of course if you want an example of that.

Comment: It just occurred to me to divide the string into two spans, each having half the number of characters.... Would that work?

Answer (score -2):

The only real way to solve this is to ensure that the `width` of the container is constrained to be (roughly) twice the length of the text.

For example, the following text is roughly 630 pixels long, so setting a `width` of `315px` in addition to `word-wrap: break-word` causes the text to be of equal length on both lines:

```css
.example {
  width: 315px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">AVeryVeryVeryVeryLongUrl/SomeFolder/SomeSubFolder/SomePage.htmlisthebestfileextension</div>
```

Note that with JavaScript's [`.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) you can calculate the existing width and set the new width automatically, though I don't *believe* this is possibly with a combination of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [`width: fit-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) in pure CSS.

```js
var example = document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0];
example.style.width = example.offsetWidth / 2 - 8 + "px";
// Half the current width, also accounting for the 8px of margin
```

```css
.example {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">AVeryVeryVeryVeryLongUrl/SomeFolder/SomeSubFolder/SomePage.htmlisthebestfileextension</div>
```